# Autodependencies with GNU make

Tags: makefile

Here is my folder view:

```
-> tree
.
├── Makefile
└── src
    ├── a10.c
    ├── a11.c
    ├── a12.c
    ├── a13.c
    ├── a14.c
    ├── a15.c
    ├── a16.c
    ├── a1.c
    ├── a2.c
    ├── a3.c
    ├── a4.c
    ├── a5.c
    ├── a6.c
    ├── a7.c
    ├── a8.c
    ├── a9.c
    ├── a.c
    └── test.h
```

`a1.c` to `a10.c` are all empty, just test, only `a.c` and `test.h` have code:

```
-> cat src/a.c
#include "test.h"

int main(void)
{
    printf("VAR = %d\n", VAR);
    printf("VAR1 = %d\n", VAR1);

    return 0;
}

-> cat src/test.h
#include <stdio.h>
```

I have a makefile with a function:

```
-> cat Makefile
ifeq '${INPUT}' ''
        STR = LATEAST
else
        STR = ${INPUT}
endif

CC        := gcc
LD        := gcc

PROGRAM = Test

MAKE_DIR        = $(PWD)
MODULES         := src
SRC_DIR         := $(addprefix $(MAKE_DIR)/,$(MODULES))
BUILD_DIR       := $(MAKE_DIR)/output

SRC             := $(foreach sdir,$(SRC_DIR),$(wildcard $(sdir)/*.c))
OBJ             := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))

INCLUDES        := $(addprefix -I,$(SRC_DIR))
INCLUDES        += -I$(MAKE_DIR)/include

#test
F_VAR = 43
F_VAR1 = 40+1+2
$(warning F_VAR=$(F_VAR), F_VAR1=$(F_VAR1))

CFLAGS :=
CFLAGS = -DVAR=41+2 -DVAR1=40+1+2


vpath %.c $(SRC_DIR)

define make-goal
$1/%.o: %.c
        @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $$< -o $$@
        @$(CC) -MM $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $$< > $1/$$*.d
        @echo "Compile    $$*.c"
endef

.PHONY: all checkdirs clean help flowchart
all: checkdirs $(BUILD_DIR)/$(PROGRAM)

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PROGRAM): $(OBJ)
        @echo "${STR}"
        @$(LD) $^ -o $@
        @echo "Generate   $(PROGRAM)"


checkdirs: $(BUILD_DIR)

$(BUILD_DIR):
        mkdir -p $@

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJ) $(BUILD_DIR)/$(PROGRAM)
        rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)

help:
        @echo "SRC DIR:    $(SRC_DIR)"
        @echo "Build DIR:  $(BUILD_DIR)"
        @echo "Source:     $(SRC)"
        @echo "Obj:        $(OBJ)"
        @echo "Includes:   $(INCLUDES)"

flowchart:
        @cflow2dot pdf ${SRC}

$(foreach sdir,$(SRC_DIR),$(eval $(call make-goal,$(sdir))))
```

My quesation is, when I touched a header file, it did not trigger a re-compilation, any problem in my makefile?

```
-> make
Makefile:28: F_VAR=43, F_VAR1=40+1+2
mkdir -p /home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_make/output
Compile    a10.c
Compile    a11.c
Compile    a12.c
Compile    a13.c
Compile    a14.c
Compile    a15.c
Compile    a16.c
Compile    a1.c
Compile    a2.c
Compile    a3.c
Compile    a4.c
Compile    a5.c
Compile    a6.c
Compile    a7.c
Compile    a8.c
Compile    a9.c
Compile    a.c
LATEAST
Generate   Test
```

the Autodependenciescan be generated:

```
-> cat src/a.d
a.o: /home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_make/src/a.c \
 /home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_make/src/test.h
```

Problem:
I modified test.h, add a error:

```
-> vim src/test.h
-> cat src/test.h
#include <stdio.h>
#error here
```

No re-compile:

```
-> make
Makefile:28: F_VAR=43, F_VAR1=40+1+2
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I add:

```
DEP := $(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(SRC))
```

Meanwhile, I add `-include` at my last line of make file:

```
-include $(DEP)
```

I did not see any improvement

Comment: As far as I can tell your Makefile doesn't use the *.d files.

Comment: @melpomene, so you mean I need use (write some code) the generated *.d fiel in makefile?

Comment: How is make supposed to know what to do with the *.d files? You need to include or sinclude the *.d files in the Makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I should:

1. write the deps

   `DPES = ...`
2. compile c file with `-MMD` option:

   `... -MMD -c $< -o $@`
3. and then, add:

   `-include $(DPES)`

Answer (score 0):

The `.d` files are makefiles that express the header-dependencies. So you need to `-include`
the `.d` files in the makefile, e.g.

```
OBJ := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))
DEP := $(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(SRC))

...

-include $(DEP)
```

Comment: I did these but still no improvement

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies files are properly generated, but you never use them : with `@$(CC) -MM $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $$< > $1/$$*.d`, make give the command to generate the dependency file, but it does not use it.

The dependencies files are little Makefiles of themselves, destined to be read by make. So, you need to tell make to read them as well as your main Makefile.
For this, you have the [include directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Include), which suspends the reading of the current makefile and read all listed files as makefiles before resuming reading of the current makefile(I'm quoting the manual here...).

Since the dependencies files won't exist on a first build, you might want to add `-` in front of it, to nullify the warning saying `no such file`.

As a side note, be sure to include the dependencies file after your default target (or to use .DEFAULT_GOAL), because if you don't, the default target will become the first found in the included files. 
Also, you might want to add your dependencies files as prerequisites of your object files, since a missing dependency file will make make miss some prerequisites.

All of this is from the make maintainer's blog, [here](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/), where you can find additional info.

## EDIT :

Sorry, I've missed it last time. If I'm not wrong, `a.o` and `$1/%.o` cannot match the same target. Even though the Makefile include files in a subdir, it did not automatically know that, and to him `a.o` and `src/a.o` are not the same (and indeed). So there is two separate rules, and one is empty, with no recipe (the one in the dependency file)
One solution might be to use the -MT flag for the dependency generation (which set the target to the string you specify, so $@ here for example.)

You might want to use the --debug option of make to catch that kind of errors ; so far, I've found it quite useful to track incorrect dependencies.

Comment: I add `-include` at last line, seems no improvement